# Mysql update data with regex

Tags: mysql, regex

Is there anyway to update rows of one `text` column and remove extra spaces in between string,

The data is actually a JSON string, Following is the example string

```
{"ID"                                      :"95703",
 "LastName"         :"Trigger",
 "FirstName"                               :"Test", ... }
```

if you notice there are annoying white spaces between `"ID"` and its value `:"95703"`,

is there anyway I can (in update query) update all rows and remove this white space (using regex)

the sample query I can run on this table is

```
UPDATE `user_log_data` SET data = {REGEX PART}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"[ ]+:
```

Try this.Replace by `":`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/31

Comment: it will only search for the records right? can we remove those spaces in update query is the real question ?

Comment: @zzlalani you can use `SUBSTR` something like this to replace as well